# Do a conditional display button form

Tags: reactjs

hello I am novice on react, I have this form and I would like that my add button appears only when there is an input on the input.
I tried this in my render. thanks

```
class App extends Component {

  state= {
    value:''
  }

  handleChange=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({value: e.currentTarget.value})
  }

  handleAdd=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    let value= [ ...this.state.value]
    value.push(this.state.value)

    }



  render () {
    let button;
    if(this.handleChange){
      button=<button>Add</button>
    }
    return (
      <div className="formulaire">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAdd}>
          <label>
            <p>Name:</p>
            <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </label>
            {button}
        </form>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this.

```
render () {
    return (
      <div className="formulaire">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAdd}>
          <label>
            <p>Name:</p>
            <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </label>
            {
            this.state.value !== ''&&
             ( <button>Add</button> )
            }
        </form>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I think it could be worked on your case.

Comment: Thanks Tess please you can explain me please.

Comment: There is a condition here... `this.state.value !== "" && ( <button>Add</button> )` is the same as doing `if(this.state.value !== "") { button = <button>Add</button> }`

Comment: You can use this conditional statement.
You can also this as like below.
{
this.state.value !== ''?
             ( <button>A</button> )
: ( <button>B</button> )
}

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways you can handle this.. (make sure to expand the snippets and run them to see the code and how it works).

**This is the more straight forward way:**

```js
const { Component } = React;

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value: "",
    added: []
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: e.currentTarget.value });
  };

  handleAdd = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      added: [...this.state.added, this.state.value],
      value: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    let button;
    let items;
    
    if(this.state.value) {
      button = <button>Add</button>
    }
    
    if(this.state.added && this.state.added.length > 0) {
      items = (
        <div>
          <h3>Added Items:</h3>
          <ul>{this.state.added.map(i => <li>{i}</li>)}</ul>
        </div>
      ) 
    }

    return (
      <div className="formulaire">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAdd}>
          <label>
            <p>Name:</p>
            <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          {button}
        </form>
        {items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**This is the exact same as above, only using different (more efficient) syntax:**

```js
const { Component } = React;

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value: "",
    added: []
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: e.currentTarget.value });
  };

  handleAdd = e => {
    const { value, added } = this.state;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      added: [...added, value],
      value: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { value, added } = this.state;
    
    let button = value && <button>Add</button>;
    
    let items = added && added.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <h3>Added Items:</h3>
          <ul>{added.map(i => <li>{i}</li>)}</ul>
        </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className="formulaire">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAdd}>
          <label>
            <p>Name:</p>
            <input value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          {button}
        </form>
        {items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```